# Link to my BBM Channel (BlackBerry Messanger Channel) from PC

Tags: blackberry, bb-messenger

Unfortunately from my country I'm not able to join to Beta-zone of BBM.
I have a website and for this website I've created a BBM channel too, I want to add a link to my website to reach my BBM channel at least for BBM users.
Is there any way to do it? What do you recommend?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a link like this to open a BBM Channel from the BlackBerry Browser.

```
<a href="bbmc:C00011F49">BlackBerry Jam Channel</a>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working! Hopefully BB will come out some sort of website for BBM Channels which can be opened from any device in a browser. I have to tell you I need to search for minutes to get to the webpage where I can admin my Channel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this and see, it works on BB phone web browser though I'm not sure if it works on other browsers. Use this link http://www.pin.bbm.com/C00410746 and end it with your own channel I'd. In the link above, C00410746 is my own channel ID. So you'll  change that and put your own ID. people will be directed to your BBM channel whenever they click on the link with their BB phone web browser.

Hope it'll help solve your problem. PIN 26eace70